# How to move back in a nest of tags in xml

Tags: xml, xslt

The best way to explain my problem is to give an example xml:

```
<block>
  <if>
    <trans>
      <trans1>
        <text1>text</text1>
      </trans1>
      <trans1>
        <text1>text</text1>
      </trans1>
    </trans>
    <if>
      <trans>
        .......
      </trans>
    </if>
  </if>
</block>
```

So to capture all the data in it, you would do a (xsl: for-each select = "block/if/trans/trans1")... get the data.
Now I want to move out of trans and trans1 so I can go into "block/if/if"...

I know I could do a separate for-each but I need to get all of this data in one cell in a table so you would need to do a nested for-each but I don't know if you can/ if it is possible to move back a bit?

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so how to do it?

Comment: If you use the Code Sample (select the XML and press Ctrl+K) it does show the <>

Comment: Please add an example of the output you are trying to generate.  It makes it easier to suggest an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> So to capture all the data in it, you would do a (xsl: for-each select = "block/if/trans/trans1")

No I wouldn't.  I almost never use for-each.  I'd do:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="block/if/trans/trans1"/>
```

> Now I want to move out of trans and trans1 so I can go into "block/if/if"..

If `trans1` is the context node, you can use the ancestor axis to get to its first `if` ancestor:

```
<xsl:template match="trans1">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::if[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

It's really not clear what you're asking, though.  Are you trying to flatten out the hierarchy, and create an HTML table from each `block` that has a `tr` for each `if`, and a `td` for each `text1` element beneath each `if`?  If so, that would require something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="block">
   <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".//if"/>
   </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="if">
   <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="trans/trans1/text1"/>
   </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text1">
   <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </td>
</xsl:template>
```

In the example above, I've assumed that you know the exact path to the `text1` descendant, as shown in your example.

If you don't know the exact path from the `if` element to the `text1` descendants, it's trickier.  You don't want to use

```
.//text1
```

because that will select *all* `text1` descendants, including the ones that are descendants of the descendant `if` elements.  That would result in the same `text1` element producing multiple `td` elements in the output - one for each `if` element it's a descendant of.  To avoid this, you need to use a pattern like:

```
text1 | .//*[name() != 'if']//text1
```

This selects any immediate `text1` children, and also any `text1` descendants that are not themselves descendants of descendant `if` elements.

Actually, this would also work:

.//text1[ancestor::if[1] = current()]

That finds all `text1` descendants whose first `if` ancestor, moving up the chain of ancestors, is the current `if` element.  This is easier to understand than the first example, but the first example probably performs better, unless the XSLT processor is really smart.

Answer (score 0):

Its not entirely clear what you need to do.  Here is my guess you want to retrieve from `/block/if` **all** `trans/trans1` elements regardless of which `if` they are found under.  On that basis try:-

```
 <xsl:for-each select="block/if//trans/trans1">
```

Note the `//` in the path is shorthand for `descendants::` and will select any occurance of `trans` at any depth below the parent `if`.